# Cannot seem to figure out this JES error, anyone know?

Tags: jython, jes

JES error
[image: JES error]

Code it's referring to
[image: Code it's referring to]

Comment: please post code and errors any in text and not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use the `repaint` function as a statement. You're missing the parenthesis on the lines:

```
repaint llama
repaint canvas
```

They should be:

```
repaint(llama)
repaint(canvas)
```